# Adjoint representation

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was just wondering why the adjoint representation of the Lie group $Ad$ and Lie algebra $ad$ are called representation. Maybe this word is derived from abstract algebra somehow, but I don't understand this terminology. For sure, $Ad$ does not enables us to represent elements in the Lie group and $ad$ does not enable us in general to represent every element in $\mathfrak{g}$, so where does the name come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *representation* comes from [representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory).  In particular, Ad gives us a group representation, and ad gives us a Lie-algebra representation.

In particular: given a Lie group $G$ and $A,B \in G$, $\operatorname{Ad}$ is a map from $G$ to $GL(\mathfrak{g})$ such that
$$
\operatorname{Ad}_A \operatorname{Ad}_B = \operatorname{Ad}_{A B}
$$
Similarly: given a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ and $X,Y \in G$, $\operatorname{ad}$ is a map from $\mathfrak g$ to $\mathfrak{gl(g)}$ such that
$$
[\operatorname{ad}_X,\operatorname{ad}_Y] = \operatorname{ad}_{[X,Y]}
$$
While these need not be **full** or **faithful** representations, they are representations nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

The linear map $\operatorname{ad}:\mathfrak{g} \to \operatorname{End}(\mathfrak{g})$, given by $x ↦ ad(x)$ is a representation of a Lie algebra, so it does enable us to "represent every element in $\mathfrak{g}$" by matrices, though not always faithfully (ad is faithful if and only if the Lie algebra has a trivial center). For example, let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}(2,K)$ be the $3$-dimensional Lie algebra consisting of traceless $2\times2$-matrices. Then $ad$ represents every element $x$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ faithfully by the matrix $ad(x)$. For details see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284164/structure-constants-for-and-the-adjoint-representation-and-meaning-in-sl2-f).